# python iterate over a list and remove any duplicates found within lists inside a dictionary and remove the duplicates

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have a list of numbers and a dictionary with names(key) and numbers(values)
i need to iterate over the list called lotto and and then check them against the values of the names in the dictionary and if i get a match remove that number from the dictionary value.

heres what i have so far but it just prints out the origanal dictionary keys and values

```
players = {'ray': [1,2,3,6,7,8,], 'al':[1,2,3,4,8,9,]}
lotto =[1,2,3,4,5,6,]

for i in players.values():  
    if i in lotto:
       players.values.remove(i)  

print (players)
```

any help appriciated

Comment: Is that the code you're actually running? I'd expect that to produce an `AttributeError`...

Comment: You will have more elegant and efficient solutions using sets instead lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the dict values in a wrong way. Take a look at the following:

```
players = {'ray': [1,2,3,6,7,8,], 'al':[1,2,3,4,8,9,]}
lotto =[1,2,3,4,5,6,]

for p, val in players.items():  
    for num in lotto:
        if num in val:
            players[p].remove(num)

print (players)  # {'al': [8, 9], 'ray': [7, 8]}
```

---

If the order of the items in the list-values is not important to you, you can use the following, faster, variant:

```
players = {'ray': [1,2,3,6,7,8], 'al':[1,2,3,4,8,9]}
lotto = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
lotto = set(lotto)

for p, val in players.items():
    players[p] = list(set(val) - lotto)

print (players)  # {'ray': [8, 7], 'al': [8, 9]}
```

which can also be condensed in the following one-liner (it recreates the `dict` though instead of modifying it):

```
players = {k: list(set(val) - lotto) for k, v in players.items()}
```

Comment: Or just `whatever = {k: sorted(set(v).difference(lotto)) for k, v in players.items()}`

Comment: If you're turning `lotto` into a `set`, no need to do the same to `val`... just use `list(lotto.difference(val))` instead

Comment: And for the one liner modifying the `dict`, how about: `players.update((k, sorted(set(v).difference(lotto))) for k,v in players.items())`?

Comment: @JonClements You are bombarding me with cool suggestions that I just can't process so fast.. xD

Comment: thats great thanks, im just starting out so the appriciate the fast respone

Comment: @JonClements `lotto.difference(val)` is not the same as doing `set(val) - set(lotto)` though. The order of operations in `set`s is important (A-B is not B-A) unless I missread you somewhere.

Comment: @JonClements As far as modifying vs recreating the `dict`, I think that in this case it is the same since your modification algorithm is essentialy updating all entries.

Comment: You're right about the `lotto.difference(val)` - that's my brain burp... hence why I was doing `set(val).difference(lotto)` The difference between the recreating and the modifying is that if you had `players2 = players` and then did `players2 = {...}` then `players2` is a completely new dictionary and `players` would still contain the original stuff... however, if you did `players2.update(...)` then `players` would be mutated as well

Comment: @JonClements You would need a deep copy, but I do get your point now. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your trying to remove your numbers from the wrong list. `players.values` is a list of **each key's value**, not **each key's individual value**. Use each key's individual value instead:

```
players = {'ray': [1,2,3,6,7,8,], 'al':[1,2,3,4,8,9,]}
lotto = [1,2,3,4,5,6,]

for key, value in players.items():
    for i in lotto:
        if i in value:
            value.remove(i)

print(players)
```

Then can be shortened however by using a dictionary comprehension:

```
players = {'ray': [1,2,3,6,7,8,], 'al':[1,2,3,4,8,9,]}
lotto =[1,2,3,4,5,6,]

players = {k: list(set(v) - set(lotto)) for k, v in players.items()}
print(players) # {'ray': [8, 7], 'al': [8, 9]}
```

Also, if the order of the list in your program doesn't matter, I recommend you use `set`s instead. They provide efficient element lookup, and make doing things like this very simple:

```
>>> players = {'ray': {1,2,3,6,7,8,}, 'al':{1,2,3,4,8,9,}}
>>> lotto = {1,2,3,4,5,6,}
>>> {k: v - lotto for k, v in players.items()}
{'ray': {8, 7}, 'al': {8, 9}}
>>>
```

Comment: assigning the `set(lotto)` would save you some time since you would not have to do it in every iteration.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis That's a good point. Note that `lotto` will loose it's order however if that matters to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter like so:

```
players = {'ray': [1,2,3,6,7,8,], 'al':[1,2,3,4,8,9,]}

lotto =[1,2,3,4,5,6]

new_players = {a:[i for i in b if i not in lotto] for a, b in players.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'al': [8, 9], 'ray': [7, 8]}
```